# Width not correctly calculated// C3 Charts

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, c3.js

I am using C3Charts in my Vue.js Dashboard Projekt. To solve the problem, that the area chart is permanently growing, when the width is not fixed, I calculated the width of the charts with the offsetWidth like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="areachart">
  <div :id="'chart-'+id"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
this.chartwidth = document.getElementById('areachart').offsetWidth;
```

Chart Config:

```
this.chartConfig = {
      size:{
        width: this.chartwidth
      },
      ...
};
```

This was working fine, but my Content Div was initialized in a way too big size. So I calculated the size via the OffsetWidth of the body in the same way. Now it seems like the "chartwidth" variable of my AreaChart component is not calculating the right value for the width. I think it is, because my Content Div has also a calculated width and before it is resized, the calculation of the chart width is finished.

Has anybody an idea if it is possible, that the one calculation waits till the first one has finished?

P.S: For better understanding: I have three components. One is the mainframe which contains the navbar and the slot for the body. The other one is my Layout component which I have titled in my description the Content Div. And the third one is my Area Chart component. The AreaChart is pasted into the Layout component and the Layout component in the Mainframe component.

Comment: can you give jsfiddel ?